# How to print SSID only?

Tags: shell-script, command-line

While I working on a script I need to print available SSID  only.
I tried this:

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID
```

I got output like this:

```
ESSID:"CoreFragment_5G"
                    ESSID:"dlink"
                    ESSID:"REDWING LABS"
                    ESSID:"Hitachi"
                    ESSID:"COMFAST"
                    ESSID:"Yash Shah"
                    ESSID:"CoreFragment"
                    ESSID:"Appbirds_Technologies"
                    ESSID:"20096641"
                    ESSID:"REDWING LABS_5G"
```

But I want to print name only. How to filter this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, using `awk`:

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
```

Or using `cut`:

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | cut -d '"' -f2
```

These commands will give you the names without `"`.

Comment: Thank you for your responce . it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | sort |uniq | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Will give you the list of available `ssid` in quotes, to get rid of quotes use `tr -d \"`, i.e,

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep ESSID | sort |uniq | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d \"
```

Here the `sort` and `uniq` only prints the unique `ssid`, and `awk` grabs only the names.